# php prepared statement bind a session

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, session-cookies

How can I set a SESSION and bind it in a prepared statement, so I can get a result from mysqli where email is equal to my SESSION['email']?

I have this code that I can't get to work, so it only gets the result with my session email:

```
public static function getById($email) {

// Initialize session array
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

// Build database query
$sql = "select * from users where email = ?";

// Open database connection
$database = new Database();

// Get instance of statement
$statement = $database->stmt_init();

// Prepare query
if ($statement->prepare($sql)) {

// Bind parameters
$statement->bind_param('s', $email);

// Execute statement
$statement->execute();

// Bind variable to prepared statement
$statement->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name, $username, $email,     $created, $active);

// Populate bind variables
$statement->fetch();

// Close statement
$statement->close();
}

// Close database connection
$database->close();

// Build new object
$object = new self;
$object->id = $id;
$object->first_name = $first_name;
$object->last_name = $last_name;
$object->username = $username;
$object->email = $email;
$object->created = $created;
$object->active = $active;
return $object;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is, but overwriting the parameter you send to the function is probably not what you want.

Comment: Scopes scopes scopes.. the `$_SESSION` supervariable is not accessible through a method scope, you'll need to pass the variable through & ensure you're using `session_start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$variable = "I am a variable";

function getVariable() {
    echo $variable;
}
```

Q) Why would the above script error?
A) Scopes...

the `$_SESSION['email']` cannot be accessed inside your method, you'll need to either global or define it or pass it in as an parameter.

```
function getById($email)
{
    echo $email;
}

session_start();
getById($_SESSION['email']);
```

Comment: got it thx used this $user = User::getById($_SESSION['email']); too call the metod and now it is working

Comment: glad it helped @nicolaiolsen

Comment: i have another question. why is it that i have to bind all the columns from my table and is it unsecure with my password even if it is private??

Comment: Use PDO rather than MySQLi, you can just use the `execute()` method and put an array of values rather than bind each parameter. & Private scopes just ensure that the variable is only accessible inside the Object unless you create a method to return its value - there is no vulnerability using this. All I'd suggest is using a unique generated salt and hashing the password with the salt, that way, if you was to accidentally print sensitive information, its encrypted & any attacks will only lead to encryption. @nicolaiolsen

Answer (score 0):

Binding essentially just sets a pointer/reference between a PHP variable and a placeholder in a query. That's it. Since you bound `$email`, any changes to `$email` will have NO effect on `$_SESSION['email']`, even though that's where `$email` came from. There's no code link between them once the assignment is completed.

You want this instead:

```
$statement->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['email']);
```

and similar for when you `bind_result` as well. There's no link between `$email` and `$_SESSION`, so anything that a DB fetch call stuffs into `$email` will have NO effect on the session var.